# How can I add a new folder to existing project on a branch, containing only new folder?

Tags: git

I'm new to git and I have an already big project (master branch) and I want to add a new folder to it.
I want to create a new branch that shows only my new folder.

I want to make changes in my new folder without affecting the original project and when will be ready I will merge it to master.

How can I create a new branch, showing only to my `new_folder` and all changes made should stay there ?

For example, consider the following structure :

```
├── App.java
├── configure.in
├── Demo
│   ├── cgi
│   │   ├── cgi0.sh
│   │   ├── cgi1.py
│   │   ├── cgi2.py
│   │   ├── cgi3.py
│   │   ├── README
│   │   └── wiki.py
|   ├── new_folder
│   │       ├── file1.sh
│   │       ├── file2.py
│   │       ├── folder43
```

Comment: I don't think folders are tracked as such. Just create a branch with your new folder (and new files in it). Unless you merge that branch back into your main branch, that folder (and the files in it) won't show up.

Comment: How can I create a Branch that contains only my new folder and not the whole project?

Comment: You can't and even if you could it would be unnecessary IMHO.

Comment: @JOseph: you *could* have a first commit on your new branch that deletes everything but the new folder, but that will clearly lead to undesired outcomes when you try to merge it back into the master branch. **Why** do you want *only* the new folder in that branch? If the *finished* (merged) product should contain both old folders and the new folder, why shouldn't the path that leads there (i.e. your new branch) also contain both?

Comment: You could off your initial commit (assuming it's empty). As others have said though this shouldn't be necessary; branching and merging is what git's all about, you don't need to remove the unchanging content, just don't modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the folder *after* you create and switch to the new branch, and it won't show up in the master branch.

```
git checkout -b new-branch
mkdir Demo/new_folder
```

Any changes you make in the folder inside this branch will stay there.

After you're done with the changes, you can merge the branch back to master with

```
git checkout master
git merge new-branch
```

Comment: @JOseph: again: **why** do you not want existing content in there? The point of a branch is that it starts in the state of the branch point and gets modified from there. What *advantage* do you see from not having the original content?

Comment: Yes it will contain everything including your new_folder. You can delete the rest manually and then make a commit. But then you will not be able to merge back, because git doesn't know where to put the new_folder in master branch. That's as simple as I can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't track folders themselves, just files and the arrangement of them in a repository.

If you want to add a folder with files, it will be tracked by git when the first file is made and running

`git add <file_path>`

But for adding a folder without a file, the standard is usually to add a blank file called '.gitkeep' into the folder, then doing a git add on that file. Also may as well make it a hidden file because in future when files are added, you can easily ignore this '.gitkeep' file.

This has its benefits when providing a definite file structure when you know its needed. But *'Less is More'* principle usually dictates that nice-to-have things (for the future) aren't good practice.

For example, say this folder gets forgotten and not used, then you have a useless folder floating about. An easy to resolve problem, but then if there are many of these useless folders embedded in a complex file structure, that's quite a concern about work practice, and the question how many other nice-to-have things have been introduced comes around.